# How to prove convexity?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, gamma-function

Let us consider the function
 $$I(p):= \frac {\Gamma(2-p)\Gamma(3p)}{(p\Gamma(p))^2}
 $$
 on the interval $(0,1),$ where $\Gamma(x)$ denotes [the gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).  How to prove its convexity there?

Comment: By the way, are asking for help or you want to tell us what to do?

Comment: By the way, where did this question come from?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the identity $p\Gamma(p)=\Gamma(p+1)$ and the expression of $\Gamma$ as a Weierstrass product, one gets
$$
I(p)=\prod_{n=0}^{+\infty}i_n(p),\qquad i_n(x)=\frac{(x+1+n)^2}{(2-x+n)(3x+n)}.
$$
Using logarithmic derivatives, one sees that each function  $i_n$ is decreasing on $(0,\frac12)$ and increasing on $(\frac12,1)$. Its (usual) second derivative is
$$
i''_n(x)=(2n+3)\left(\frac3{(3x+n)^3}+\frac1{(2-x+n)^3}\right),
$$
hence each $i_n$ is positive and convex on $(0,1)$. [Thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27571/6179), their product $I$ is convex and decreasing on $(0,\frac12)$ and is convex and increasing on $(\frac12,1)$.

Every function continuous on $(0,1)$, convex and decreasing on $(0,\frac12)$, and convex and increasing on $(\frac12,1)$, is convex on $(0,1)$ because every chord from $x$ in $(0,\frac12)$ to $x'$ in $(\frac12,1)$ lies above the chords from $x$ to $\frac12$ and from $\frac12$ to $x'$. This proves that $I$ is convex on $(0,1)$.

Comment: I just want to add that it might be worth mentioning [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225514/proving-that-a-limit-of-a-convex-functions-is-convex) too.

Comment: @Tunococ True. Thanks.