# Convexity of pointwise limit of convex functions

Tags: real-analysis

As prep for an exam, I am trying to prove that the pointwise limit of a sequence of convex functions $f_n (x)$ (**defined over an open and convex subset $C$ of a finite-dimensional vector space**) is a convex function.
In this discussion:

[Proving that a limit of a convex functions is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225514/proving-that-a-limit-of-a-convex-functions-is-convex)

One of the answers explains that:
If $f_n\to f$ pointwise then 
$$f_n(\lambda a+(1-\lambda) b)\to f(\lambda a+(1-\lambda) b)$$ and $$\lambda f_n(a)+(1-\lambda)f_n(b)\to \lambda f(a)+(1-\lambda)f(b).$$

However this does not prove that $f(\lambda a+(1-\lambda) b) \leq  \lambda f(a)+(1-\lambda)f(b)$, which is crucial to prove convexity. Could someone help?

Comment: Why do we need to restrict to $C$? Do you have a reference for that? From the answer below I do not understand where I need that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f_n(\lambda a+(1-\lambda) b)\leq \lambda f_n(a)+(1-\lambda)f_n(b)$$

as you said take limits on both side, you get

$$f(\lambda a+(1-\lambda) b)\leq \lambda f(a)+(1-\lambda)f(b).$$

what is the problem?

Are you asking why $\lim a_n\geq \lim b_n$ should follow from $a_n\geq b_n$ for every $n$?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is precisely what does not look obvious to me

Comment: @user114618 Think about it this way: how can $\lim (a_n-b_n) < 0$ if every number on the left hand side is positive? how can positive numbes converge to a strictly negative number?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!