# Is that true that the limiting function which is a function series of convex functions is also convex?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is that true that the limiting function which is a function series of convex functions is also convex?

I'm not sure what is the exact name of this "limiting function" in English, after the German terminology this is "Grenzfunktion" .

I mean this " A sequence of functions $ (f_{n}) $converges uniformly to a limiting function $ f$ on a set $ E $"

Is this maybe the answer to my question?

[Proving that a limit of a convex functions is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225514/proving-that-a-limit-of-a-convex-functions-is-convex)

I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: As far as I know, the English word is "limit function" or simply "limit" (if there is no possibility of misunderstanding).

Comment: In English the phrase " $f$ is the uniform limit of a sequence $(f_n)_n$ of functions" is common. ...And  "function sequence" should  not be used, due to the  undefinability of English grammar. ... In English a "series" usually means  something like  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n.$

Comment: Your proposed link is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Finite sums of convex functions are convex and pointwise limit of convex functions is convex so the sum of a pointwise convergent series of convex functions is also convex.